# SPARQL - How to use group_concate and Order By together?

Tags: sparql

I am new to SPARQL, I have observed that when I am using group_concate function and ORDER BY Clause together, it stops ordering. I don't know why its happening.

Please let me know the solution
Thanks in advance
sayali

Comment: that is not part of the standard, ordering won't necessarily be propagated into the `group_concat` function not even when you sort first in a subquery. You can get lucky depending on the implementation, but there is in fact no guarantee. Like `select ?s (group_concat(?o; separator=", ") as ?values) {select ?o {?s :p ?o} order by ?s ?o } group by ?s` most likely won't lead to sorted values per group.

Comment: It's by the way a known limitation and an open issue for SPARQL 1.2 standard: https://github.com/w3c/sparql-12/issues/9